# ADFS 2.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2

Wanted to know if ADFS 2.0 can be installed on Windows Server 2012? The below link says it can be installed and gives command to install but that command fails throwing the error 'ad-federation-services' is a invalid role.

http://blog.msgeneral.nl/2012/11/installing-and-configuring-adfs-on.html#comment-form

I have also tried installing using the command provided in another link which mentions about installing ADFS 2.1. But it installs ADFS 3.0.
http://www.flexecom.com/install-adfs-2-1-on-windows-server-2012-for-office-365-part-1/

I am verifying the version of ADFS installed using the below link and I cant find FSConfig.exe file.

"jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/gathering-architectural-details-from-your-adfs-infrastructure-adfs-version/"

Is ADFS 2.1 installed on Windows Server 2012 and ADFS 3.0 installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 by default?

Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: This fits squarely under the guise of 'networking-related infrastructure administration'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is ADFS 2.1 installed on Windows Server 2012 and ADFS 3.0 installed
>   on Windows Server 2012 R2 by default?"

Yes.

Comment: Is there anyway to override the default behavior and install different version?

Comment: I have never tried, so I am only 99.999999% sure. Answer is  *no*. But I wouldn't even try it because there are very special dependencies on implementations, namespaces etc.
I also assume that Microsoft will not support it. Given the amount of fixes and re-fixes lately, I would advise strongly against it.

Comment: I had not seen the on-hold. I assume that you wanted to run your old custom code on 2012R2. Don't go there, ADFS on 2012R2 has done some really intricate things with namespaces, assemblies etc. You will have serious trouble understanding it and making it run (if it can). If you rephrase to a programming question and namespaces, then it should be OK. Otherwise it was not supposed to be here.